# Where did Aristotle say that the more self-evident something is, the more difficult it is to see?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

18:45 of [this](https://youtu.be/r1V4w38v2mI) claims that Aristotle said that the more self-evident something is, the more difficult it is to see (reminiscent of: "hidden in plain sight"). Where did Aristotle say this?

Comment: In various places (e.g. beginning of *Physics*) Aristotle says that we should start with what is evident for us: if it is even more difficult to see, would this pet idea of his  be meaningful?